# vCenter reset root account password

Tags: vmware, esxi, vcenter

Recently took over management of some servers and I can no longer connect to our vCenter to manage our VMs. We don't have SSO and as far as I know, we only have one account, root.

I am wondering if the password has expired on the account, as I have seen other threads indicating that the error "Invalid Credentials" can come about with an expired password. I have yet to figure out how to reset this password though.

If anyone has any ideas or advice on how to get on I would be very appreciate!

Comment: I have never hear of root password to expire. I have know the root certificate authority certificate to expire.  Can you provide more specifics?

Comment: I didn't think it did either, but after we upgraded from ESXi 5.5 to 6.5, it seems to have enforced a 90 day policy (along with changing username root to root@vsphere.local)

Comment: I recently upgraded my own 5.5 infrastructure to 6.5 and that didn’t happen to me.  So how about those specifics?

Comment: I have managed to get on through https://<ESXi-IP>/ui instead of https://<vSphere-IP>:9443/vsphere-client using the username and password before the upgrade. Very strange.

Comment: Typically vSphere would be vSphere.local and ESXi would be root.